# Does Chrome on Android support User Verification on security key using Webauthn / FIDO2?

Tags: android, google-chrome, fido-u2f, webauthn, fido

I'm building a site that is using [Webauthn](https://webauthn.guide) for passwordless log in. Currently, this is working great on Chrome for Windows and macOS.

I'm using a YubiKey 5 to test my implementation which supports using a PIN to provide [User Verification](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn/#user-verification) instead of just plain User Presence (i.e. user touched key's button).

[image: Windows PIN prompt]

However, when I try to use this same site on Chrome 76 on Android 9, I am not prompted for a pin and so the User Verification flag is not set and my log in (by design) fails.

Google has made a big deal about Android 7+ being FIDO2 compliant but I can't seem to find any mention of this critical missing feature other than [an outdated article](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/05/webauthn) that mentions that:

> We are also working on more advanced flows enabled by CTAP 2 and WebAuthn, such as PIN protected authenticators, local selection of accounts (instead of typing a username or password), and fingerprint enrollment.

Fingerprint enrollment is now supported; are PIN protected authenticators *still* unsupported even when the Windows and macOS versions of Chrome 76 do?

This is the relevant part of my call to `navigator.credentials.create()` that should be requiring user verification:

```
"authenticatorSelection": {"requireResidentKey": false, "userVerification": "required"}
```

Comment: You might want to check the Chromium bug list: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list?q=component%3ABlink%3EWebAuthentication&can=1 and see if there is a similar issue ticket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that this is currently not implemented in Android's Google Play Services. [I've filed a bug with the Chromium project which is tracking its eventual implementation.](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=997538)